# Duals of embeddings in the space of distributions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

If $ \Lambda \colon X \hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}'$ is a continuous embedding of a normed vector space $X$ into the space of distributions (for example $X=L^p$), is it true that the dual of $\Lambda(X)$ (equipped with the topology of $\mathcal{D}'$) is the same as the dual of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting into distributions, consider a simpler example: $X=L^2[0,1]$ continuously embeds into $Y=L^1[0,1]$ via the identity map $\Lambda f=f$. The dual of $\Lambda(X)$ is $Y^* = L^\infty[0,1]$, since $\Lambda(X)$ is dense in $Y$. This is not the same as $X^*$.

On the positive note, the adjoint operator $\Lambda^* : Y^*\to X^*$ is a continuous embedding. But it is not surjective.

Same thing with distributions. The dual of $L^p$ is $L^q$. But a general $L^q$ function cannot act on distributions. E.g., it cannot act on Dirac delta. So, the set of continuous linear functions on $\Lambda(X)\subset \mathcal D'$ is smaller that $X^*$.

Comment: but Lq only needs to act on Lp functions within the distributions, so i think the problem is whether it acts continuously. i think it does for Lp if 1<p<infinity, but i assume the dual only turns out to be the closure of the schwartz functions within the original dual. i cant prove this though

Comment: @Bananach If it acted continuously, the action would extend continuously to all distributions. Which is does not.

Comment: but Lq does act on Lp simply via integrating. And this action is continuous bc if  $fn \to f\in Lp$ in the distributions topology, then $\int fn \phi \to \int f \phi $ for all test functions$\phi$, but since they are dense in Lq the same holds for $\phi$ in Lq (hoelder)

Comment: @Bananach No. Take $f_n = n(\chi_{[0,1/n]} - \chi_{[-1/n,0]})$. Then $f_n\to 0$ in the sense of distributions. However, $\int f_n \chi_{[0,1]} = 1\not\to0$.

Comment: @Bananach Your mistake is in *since these test functions are dense*. Convergence when tested by smooth functions is different from convergence when tested by continuous functions, which is different from convergence tested by $L^2$ functions, which is different from convergence tested by $L^1$ functions... "Dense" is not a magic wand.

Comment: thanks for your patience! (and sorry for deleting my comment, after realizing my mistake I hoped I would delete it before you saw it and added another comment)